# How to determine Translate Y positioning with PopperJS

Tags: javascript, position, popper.js

I am creating a drop-down control as a reusable web component and I decided to use PopperJS to handle the positioning of the drop-down items.

I am experimenting with sub-items, I've created a little check to determine the [placement](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/constructors/#placement):

```js
placement: this.parentElement.nodeName == "MY-ELEMENT" // Check if parent is a menu
  ? "right"
  : "bottom"
```

I have [created a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-4bjeqq?file=src%2Findex.js).

The sub-items open to the right okay, but if you `F12` and inspect the items they are translated -60px, so the items are positioned in the centre rather than positioned at the bottom going down.

If I choose placement `right-end` then the items are positioned too far down, what I want is for translate Y to be `0` not `-60`.

How do I determine that the items should be positioned correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the StackBlitz working properly?

I think you could use the offset modifier to add some skidding:

```js
createPopper(reference, popper, {
  placement: this.parentElement.nodeName == "MY-ELEMENT"
            ? "right"
            : "bottom",
  modifiers: [
    {
      name: 'offset',
      options: {
        offset: ({ placement, reference, popper }) => {
          if (placement === 'right') {
            return [60, 0];
          } else {
            return [];
          }
        },
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

It could be `60` instead of `-60`, not sure if I got exactly what you want.
You can check the usage here: https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/modifiers/offset/